# TinyMCE error: "The advcode enterprise plugin is not enabled on your API key." but I dont have 'advcode' plugin anywhere

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE editor with basic plugins and toolbar yet a warning mentioned in the title always shows up. It doesn't affect the work of the editor, it's just annoying. These are the plugins and toolbar I am using with VueJS:

```
import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'
```

```
<editor v-if="!isLinkSelected"
api-key="MY_API_KEY" 
:init="{
    plugins: 'lists, image, imagetools, link, table, media, textcolor, colorpicker',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | align | bold italic underline | forecolor backcolor | styleselect | blockquote | link | image | media | formatselect | fontsizeselect | removeformat | numlist bullist | table',
    menu: {},
    images_upload_url: 'editor-upload.php',
    automatic_uploads: true,
    relative_urls : false,
    remove_script_host : false,
    file_browser_callback_types: 'file image media',
    convert_urls : true,
    link_list : page_link_list,
    height : 500,
}"
v-model="editor.content">
</editor>
```

Comment: Would you post more code of your TinyMCE editor integration? From where do you get the source files?

Comment: Check that the plugin list in JS is the same as the one you've specified, maybe advcode is being added somewhere else during the render process?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out what was my problem. 
I realized that none of my modifications in the Vue component file was visible on the page. I was watching with `npm watch` and it always updated the .js files accordingly, but it was hard cached somehow so I had to `npm update` and regenerate my js files with `npm watch` then clear browser cache and my modifications were visible on the site instantly.